# Handle Input with Same State Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a shopping cart application and I ran into a problem where all my inputs have the same state value. Everything works fine but when I type in one input box, it's the same throughout all my other inputs.

I tried adding a name field to the input and setting my initial state to undefined and that works fine but the numbers don't go through.

How do we handle inputs to be different when they have the same state value? Or is this not possible / dumb to do?

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: {
      1: {
        id: 1, name: 'Yeezys', price: 300, remaining: 5
      },  

      2: {
        id: 2, name: 'Github Sweater', price: 50, remaining: 5
      },

      3: {
        id: 3, name: 'Protein Powder', price: 30, remaining: 5
      }
    },
    itemQuantity: 0
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Shopping Area</h1>
        {Object.values(items).map(item => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <h2>{item.name}</h2>
            <h2>$ {item.price}</h2>
            {item.remaining === 0 ? (
              <p style={{ 'color': 'red' }}>Sold Out</p>
            ) : (
              <div>
                <p>Remaining: {item.remaining}</p>
                <input 
                  type="number"
                  value={ itemQuantity }
                  onChange={e => this.setState({ itemQuantity: e.target.value})}
                  placeholder="quantity"
                  min={1}
                  max={5}
                />
                <button onClick={() => this.addItem(item)}>Add To Cart</button>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You use the same state inside multiple items and wonder that ... they got the same state?

Comment: @JonasW I know that they hold the same value but I was wondering if there was a way to make them unique. If i have 10000 items, I'm not gonna have 10000 inputs for each

Comment: @ionizer Nice solution. I'll try that. :)

Comment: Or, you could probably insert a new property into those items to track quantity and dynamically set it similar to how I did with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution which the problem is loosely interpreted, but it does work without having to create another component. As you know, you needed to separate the state of each items in the cart. I did this by dynamically initializing and setting the quantity states of each item. You can see the state changes with this example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { quantities: {} }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let itemIDs = ['1', '2', '3', 'XX']; //use your own list of items
    itemIDs.forEach(id => {
      this.setState({quantities: Object.assign(this.state.quantities, {[id]: 0})});
    })
  }

  render() {
    let list = Object.keys(this.state.quantities).map(id => {
      return (
        <div>
          <label for={id}>Item {id}</label>
          <input
            id={id}
            key={id}
            type="number"
            value={this.state.quantities[id]}
            onChange={e => {
              this.setState({quantities: Object.assign(this.state.quantities, {[id]: e.target.value})})
            }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })
    return (
      <div>
        {list}
        <div>STATE: {JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

You can modify the state structure to your liking.

Comment: Ended up going with your answer as I went ahead and applied a quantity property to each of my items and set to be target value. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using same state key for all input, All input take value from one place and update to one place. To avoid this you have to use separate state. I suppose you are trying to show input for a list of item.

To achive you can create a component for list item and keep state in list item component. As each component have their own state, state value will not conflict.

Here is an example

```
class CardItem extends Component {
    state = {
        number: 0
    }

    render() {
        render (
            <input type="text" value={this.state.number} onChange={e => this.setState({ number: e.target.value })} />
        )
    }
}

class Main extends Component {
    render () {
        const list = [0,1,2,3,4]

        return (
            list.map(item => <CardItem data={item} />)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Should've thought of this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I usually handle this scenario. You say that you get an array of items? Each item object should contain a key to store the value (`count` in my example). You can use a generic onChange handler to update an individual item in the array. So now, your state is managing the list of items instead of each individual input value. This makes your component much more flexible and it will be able to handle any amount of items with no code changes:

```js
const itemData = [
{ id: 0, count: 0, label: 'Number 1' },
{ id: 1, count: 0, label: 'Number 2' },
{ id: 2, count: 0, label: 'Number 3' },
{ id: 3, count: 0, label: 'Number 4' }
];

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    items: itemData
  }
  
  handleCountChange = (itemId, e) => {
    // Get value from input
    const count = e.target.value;
    this.setState( prevState => ({
      items: prevState.items.map( item => {
        // Find matching item by id
        if(item.id === itemId) {
          // Update item count based on input value
          item.count = count;
        }
        return item;
      })
    }))
  };
  
  renderItems = () => {
    // Map through all items and render inputs
    return this.state.items.map( item => (
       <label key={item.label}>
          {item.label}:
          <input
            type="number"
            value={item.count}
            onChange={this.handleCountChange.bind(this, item.id)}
          />
        </label>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       {this.renderItems()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same state for the both inputs. Try to use a different state for each one like that:

```
class App extends Component {


state = {
    number: ""
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={this.state.number}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ number: e.target.value })}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          value={this.state.number2}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ number2: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```