# Dynamically generated inputs changing same state object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a functional component that generates multiple input fields based on a prop. How can I make the inputs change certain key value pairs in my state.

What I'm trying to do is similar to this question: [Handle Input with Same State Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706285/handle-input-with-same-state-value)

However typescript does not allow me to.

```
interface FieldProps {
    labels: string[]
}


function InputFields(props: FieldProps) {
    const initState = {}
    props.labels.forEach(label => {
        Object.assign(initState, {[label]: ""})
    })
    const [value, setValue] = useState<Object>(initState)

    const onChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log("Event catch: ", event.currentTarget.value)
        setValue({[event.currentTarget.name] : event.currentTarget.value})
    }

    const renderItem = (id: number, label: string) => {
        console.log("Render id: ", id," label: ", label)
        return(
            <div>
                    <input
                        onChange={onChange}
                        value={value[label]} // error: type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'
                        id={id.toString()}
                        type="text"
                    ></input>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const renderItems = () => {
        return props.labels.map((item, i) => renderItem(i, item))
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form className="grey_container-3col">
                { renderItems() }
            </form>
            <br-button  // ignore this, custom component
                icon="magnifying-glass" 
                label="Pesquisar" 
                type="primary"
                onClick={()=> {
                    alert("State value: " + value)
                }}
            />
        </>
    )

}
```

Comment: `useState<Record<string, string>>(initState)` instead of `useState<Object>(initState)`?

Comment: @caTS That worked. Thanks! I'm pretty new to typescript